# How to avoid nested for loops in arraylist to retrieve data in Java?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, pojo

We have POJO classes Employee and Projects. While the Master class has the object of Employee and ArrayList of Projects. We are also creating an Arraylist of Master in Main class where data is assigned and retrieved.

Employee POJO

```java
public class Employee {
    Integer empID;
    String name;
    String desig;

    public Employee(Integer empID, String name, String desig) {
        this.empID = empID;
        this.name = name;
        this.desig = desig;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "empID=" + empID +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", desig='" + desig + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public Integer getEmpID() {
        return empID;
    }

    public void setEmpID(Integer empID) {
        this.empID = empID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDesig() {
        return desig;
    }

    public void setDesig(String desig) {
        this.desig = desig;
    }
}
```

Project POJO

```java
public class Project {

    Integer projID;
    String projName;
    String location;
    Integer empID;

    public Project(Integer projID, String projName, String location, Integer empID) {
        this.projID = projID;
        this.projName = projName;
        this.location = location;
        this.empID = empID;
    }

    public Integer getProjID() {
        return projID;
    }

    public void setProjID(Integer projID) {
        this.projID = projID;
    }

    public String getProjName() {
        return projName;
    }

    public void setProjName(String projName) {
        this.projName = projName;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Integer getEmpID() {
        return empID;
    }

    public void setEmpID(Integer empID) {
        this.empID = empID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Project{" +
                "projID=" + projID +
                ", projName='" + projName + '\'' +
                ", location='" + location + '\'' +
                ", empID=" + empID +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Master POJO

```java
public class Master {
    Employee employee;
    ArrayList<Project> projects;

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public ArrayList<Project> getProjects() {
        return projects;
    }

    public void setProjects(ArrayList<Project> projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
    }

    public Master(Employee employee, ArrayList<Project> projects) {
        this.employee = employee;
        this.projects = projects;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Master{" +
                "employee=" + employee +
                ", projects=" + projects +
                '}';
    }

}
```

Main class

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Master> masters = new ArrayList<>();

        addData(masters);

        fetchData(masters);

    }

    private static void addData(ArrayList<Master> masters) {

        // WE ARE INITIALIZING MASTERS IN THIS BLOCK WITH DATA FROM DB
    }


    private static void fetchData(ArrayList<Master> masters) {

        for (int i = 0; i < masters.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Employee "+(i+1)+" "+masters.get(i).getEmployee().getEmpID()+" "
            +masters.get(i).getEmployee().getName()+" "+masters.get(i).getEmployee().getDesig());

            for (int j = 0; j < masters.get(i).getProjects().size(); j++) {
                System.out.println("Projects "+masters.get(i).getProjects().get(j).getProjID()+" "
                +masters.get(i).getProjects().get(j).getProjName()+" "+masters.get(i).getProjects().get(j).getLocation()
                +" "+masters.get(i).getProjects().get(j).getEmpID());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to remove this nested for loop in the fetchData() method in the Main class, to improve the time complexity?

Comment: no need to write your title in caps, people don't take kindly to it, probably a good idea to change it to a standard format

Comment: Using all capitals is the internet-equivalent of shouting, which is pretty rude to do to people you want to help you. I've edited it this time, but please keep this in mind for future posts.

Comment: The data structures you're using aren't suitable for what you want. If you want to avoid the costly loops, consider using a different structure, like a HashMap, HashSet, etc, where you could retrieve the data at once.

Comment: Perhaps you can store Hashmap <Employee, List<Project>>